# Can I use RasPi as a thin client to access LOB applications on Windows Terminal Server?

Tags: rdp

Has anyone in the corporate sector used RasPi as a thin client to access 
centralized LOB applications on Windows Terminal Server; and how is the performance ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Raspberry Pi thin client project:

http://rpitc.blogspot.co.uk/

This might provide you with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used one as an X11 client, using XDMCP and  it was very slow, then again, the network is a bottleneck for that, whereas Windows's RDP does good compression, so you may well have better results!